# PHP References - the &

Tags: php

Why is it that the **&** is attached to the parameter name in the function header, not - as would logically be expected - the variable in the calling scope?

For example:

```
<?php

function func(&$par)
{
    $par++;
}

$var=1;
func($var);
print $var;   //prints 2

?>
```

the same is witnessed inside the parenthesis for foreach where you write ($array as **&**$value), not (**&**$array as $value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer from PHP itself:

> There is no reference sign on a function call - only on function
>   definitions. Function definitions alone are enough to correctly pass
>   the argument by reference.

More details here:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

Comment: Adding to this answer, is not `(&$array as $value)` because you change `$value` by reference, you are never touching `$array`, this variable is just to read.

Comment: When simply assigning by reference, we can, for example write, write: $var1=0; $var2 = &$var1; $var2++: echo $var2; //prints 2